# Проблема с назначением своего обработчика onClick

Tags: javascript

Пару дней как начал знакомиться со скриптами.Не ругайте плиз,подскажите мои ошибки.Думаю они и в форме и в скрипте.Заранее благодарен.

```
<head>
<script language="JavaScript>
var chars="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
function genpass() {

 password = '';
 for( i=0;i<6;i++ )
     password = (Math.random();
 document.getElementById('pass').value = password;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <for name="first"
 ÁËÀ ÁËÀ<br>
 <input type="text" name="password">
 <input type="button" name="pass" value="Test Input" onClik="genpass(this.form)">
</body>
```

Обычный генератор. Но и с формой что-то не то.Я понял, что должен ввести функцию `length`, как это правильно сделать?
    pass=?(math floor(math random *lent));так норм?

Comment: @kot197676, напишите что программа должна делать. Это не так очевидно )

Comment: Че то у вас английские словечки похрамывают

Comment: обычный генератор  pass = ?(Mathfloor(Mathrandom *lent));
из какого соображения выбирать ? и что мне поставить?

Answer (score 1):

Вы это скопировали или набивали вручную? А то какие-то for и onClik у вас, где закрывающий тэг формы, где параметр action у формы? Это что за - ÁËÀ ÁËÀ?

> <**for** name="first" ÁËÀ ÁËÀ<br> <input
> type="text" name="password"> <input
> type="button" name="pass" value="Test
> Input" **onClik**="genpass(this.form)">
> </body>

```
<form name="first" action="">
ÁËÀ ÁËÀ<br />
<input type="text" name="password" />
<input type="button" name="pass" value="Test Input" onClick="genpass(this.form)" />
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Вручную.А текст  БЛА БЛА после редактора

Comment: genpass() у вас тоже явно не делает, то что вы задумывали. Рекоммендую срочно хотя бы бегло просмотреть какую-нибудь книженцию по HTML и JS, например, Прохоренок Н.А. - HTML, JavaScript, PHP и MySQL. Джентльменский набор Web-мастера

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки.Это мой первый скрипт.А книгу обязательно посмотрю.Мне когда делаюкак то лучше доходит.

Comment: @kot197676, еще можете в дополнение найти и скачать себе редактор, который бы подсвечивал явные ошибки в языках HTML, CSS и javascript. Это сильно упростит работу.